# MVC3 RadioButtonFor with enum

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm having problems with the HtmlHelper, RadioButtonFor and an enum in my model. I have a strongly typed view, and I want the checkboxes to toggle my enum property.

```
Enum.cs

public enum Values{
    Value1,
    Value2
}
```

---

```
Model.cs

public class Model{
    public Values MyProp{ get; set; }
;
```

---

```
View.cshtml

@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyPropi, Values.Values1)
```

---

```
Controller.cs
public ActionResult WizardFirstStep()
{
    var model = new Model();
    return View(model);
}
```

If I set the MyProperty value in the controller, the RadioButton is checked as expected. But after a post to the next wizard step, which gets the model as parameter, the property isn't set.

If it will help you to understand what I mean: If it would be C# and WPF I would use a IValueConverter.

btw: I use a HtmlHelper.ActionLink to get the model to the controller.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry for any inconvenience. After posting here, I found the solution very quickly. My ActionLink was not submitting the @Html.BeginForm form. So i changed my radiobutton to:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyPropi, Values.Values1, new{ onClick = "this.form.submit();" })
```

which submits the correct value to my controller. For the moment this is okay. Maybe the ActionLink can post back the form data.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it should work as I have done the same thing before:

```
@Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.MyProp, (int)Values.Values1, model.MyProp == Values.Values1)
```

Notice the cast to `int`, it ensures the correct value is used for html.

**EDIT**: Sorry, I think you also need the third parameter to ensure the correct radio button is set when loading the view.

I also assumed `MyPropi` was a typo and changed it to `MyProp`, please ensure this matches up correctly at your end

Comment: I'm afraid, but that doesn't work. My problem is: how to get the correct value, depending on which radiobutton is toggled, into my model. At the moment I'm routing the Model via ActionLink into the controller. @Html.ActionLink("next", "WizardSecondStep", Model)

Comment: I see. So that won't work, you need to post your form each step if you want the model binding to work. So instead of an ActionLink use a submit button to post the form. Having the model as a parameter of your post method

Answer (score -1):

For Aspx pages:
    <%:Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.YourProp, Selected value of your enum like : demo1.enum1.value2)