# Html.RadioButtonFor default checked

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How can I checked default radio button conditional?
Following is my code:

> Enum

```
 public enum yesNo
 {
        Yes = 0,
        No = 1
 }
```

> View

```
<div class="form-group">
       @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Member_Addiction, new { @class = "  col-md-3" })
       <div class="col-md-4">
             @foreach (var e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(RKDYM.clsEnums.yesNo)))
             {
                   <label class="radio-inline">
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Member_Addiction, (int)e, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} })@e.ToString()
                   </label>
             }
       </div>
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Member_Addiction)
</div>
```

> Model

```
[DisplayName("Do you have addiction?")]        
public bool Member_Addiction { get; set; }
```

Comment: What if you assign Member_Addiction default value?

Comment: @renathy It will be 1(No). If need to pass default value then how to pass it?

Comment: In your model constructor, make `Member_Addiction == true`; Or set `[DefaultValue(true)]` attribute to your property,

Comment: @vortex Where to mention Member_Addiction == true in model.

Comment: I told you, in the constructor.

Comment: @vortex                                                                                            public Member()
{
           Member_Addiction =true;
}                                                                                                               Is it right?                                                                                                 Below is not working                                                           [DefaultValue(true)]
 public bool Member_Addiction { get; set; }

Comment: or try with html attribute `new {@class = "form-control", @checked = "checked" }`

Comment: @vortex I already tried it but didn't work

Comment: look here then, it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863790/mvc3-radiobuttonfor-with-enum

Comment: You attempting to bind a boolean value to the enum values "Yes" or "No" which does not work (a boolean can only have a value of `true` or `false`. Either use `Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.Member_Addiction)` or if you want radio buttons then `@Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m.Member_Addiction, true) @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=> m.Member_Addiction, false) `. Not clear what your enum is for and there is no point in `@Html.ValidationMessageFor()`

Comment: @vortex you are correct. I have removed new { htmlAtrribute = and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Set default value in constructor of your model. 
I have tried the following code and it works (it sets default value and if user changes value it returns correct value to controller).

```
public enum yesNo
{
    Yes = 0,
    No = 1
}

public class TestModel
{
    public TestModel()
    {
        this.Member_Addiction = false;
    }


    [DisplayName("Do you have addiction?")]        
    public bool Member_Addiction { get; set; }

}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Member_Addiction, new { @class = "  col-md-3" })
        <div class="col-md-4">
            @foreach (TestProject.Models.yesNo e in Enum.GetValues(typeof(TestProject.Models.yesNo)))
            {
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    @{ if (e == TestProject.Models.yesNo.No)
                       {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Member_Addiction, false)@e.ToString() 
                       }
                       else
                       {
                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Member_Addiction, true)@e.ToString() 
                       }
                    }
                </label>
            }
        </div>
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Member_Addiction)
    </div>
    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

P.S. Maybe you can find better sollution than using "if" statement in your View.

Answer (score -1):

I have replaced following line

```
new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"} }
```

with

```
new { @class = "form-control", @checked = "checked" }
```

Comment: Which means even if the initial value of `Member_Addiction` is `true` the 'No' radio button will always be selected and then if you pick the 'Yes' button, the value of `Member_Addiction` will always be false when you post back. I suggest you start learning some fundamental basics of MVC.